# DataBufferByte cannot be cast to DataBufferInt?

Tags: java, sprite, bufferedimage

I want to store RGB values in a pixel array like so:

```
pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

where `image` is:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

I read the file using `ImageIO` and it read fine, it's this part that's the problem. Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
at SpritePractice.render(SpritePractice.java:114)
at SpritePractice.run(SpritePractice.java:75)
at SpritePractice.start(SpritePractice.java:124)
at SpritePractice.main(SpritePractice.java:132)
```

And pixels is an int array like so: `int[] pixels`
What do I do? As a side question, can somebody explain casting and what it does? thanks!

EDIT:

Printed out `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()` on console

Heres output:

```
java.awt.image.DataBufferByte@716925b0
```

Clearly there's something wrong here. I specified that `BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);` and it's reading `DataBufferByte`...

Comment: here you go http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't work, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB should store the image data in an int[], it works for me. ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
    .getData() confirms it

Comment: Are you sure that is the image causing the error and not some other image?

Comment: It's the same image. Not getting any errors reading it.

Comment: "image = new BufferedImage(...) " and "I read the file using ImageIO and it read fine"... How do you do this? And are you sure `image` is the same after reading? There's obviously more to your code than what you have posted here. Please post the relevant code (or preferably an SSCCE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably doing it wrong. :-)

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

...should create an image with an `IntegerInterleavedRaster` and `DataBufferInt` (it does for me on OS X, using all my installed Java 6 and 7 JREs). Try printing the raster and the data buffer *right after creation*. I'm sure it will print what you originally expected.

**Speculative answer below:**

You haven't posted the relevant parts of your code, but I would guess based on the comments that you are a) creating an empty image and assigning it to `image`, then b) reading another image using ImageIO and assigning the result to `image`, replacing the previous value of `image`. The image now has a raster and data buffer of type byte. You then try to cast to int type, and boom.

Now, it is possible to make `ImageIO` read into a pre-created `BufferedImage`, or just specify the type. But this is plugin- and source-specific (ie: there's no guarantee it will support `TYPE_INT_RGB`). To query the reader what image layouts it supports, do something like:

```
ImageInputStream stream = ...;
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
if (readers.hasNext()) {
    ImageReader reader = readers.next();

    try {
        reader.setInput(stream);

        ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

        Iterator<ImageTypeSpecifier> specs = reader.getImageTypes();

        while (specs.hasNext()) {
            ImageTypeSpecifier spec = specs.next();

            if (/*spec is for TYPE_INT_RGB*/) {
                // Either pass your pre-allocated image:
                reader.setDestination(image); 

                // *OR* simply tell the reader what type you like the result to be:
                reader.setDestinationType(spec);
            }
        }

        // TODO: Handle the case where there's no match among the ImageTypeSpecifiers

        // In case image was passed, it will be the same image returned here
        image = reader.read(0, param); 
    }
    finally {
        reader.dispose();
    }
}
```

Casting does what it has always done, but I don't think that is your problem here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();` is of type `java.awt.image.DataBufferByte` as inferred from the exception.

You are attempting to cast i.e convert `java.awt.image.DataBufferByte` to `java.awt.image.DataBufferInt` which do not lie in the same inheritance hierarchy.

Remember this,

```
You can cast a sub type to super type (Liskov Substitution Principle).
When casting a super type to sub type a `ClassCasteException` will be thrown.
Also, if you attempt to cast classes which do not lie in the same inheritance  
hierarchy will always throw `ClassCasteException` at runtime.
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a DataBufferInt since I set the BufferedImage to type: `TYPE_INT_RGB`?

Comment: @user2052855 [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839223/java-awt-image-databufferbyte-cannot-be-cast-to-java-awt-image-databufferint) can help you

Answer (score -1):

This is not so hard to understand:

`DataBufferByte` and `DataBufferInt` both extend `DataBuffer` so they are basically on different branches of the class hierarchy.

This is like trying to cast different implementations of the same interface to each other.

Comment: The problem is that the type is not what it should be, check my comment to OP.