# Loading image from file as given "type" into an OpenCV Mat?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, bufferedimage

I recently started working with the Java bindings for OpenCV to make a quick and dirty project to do template matching. Basically I am trying to read a set of jpg images (saved in MS Paint) into `Mat`s and then use template matching to find their locations from a screen shot taken with `Java.Robot`.

When it comes time to do the template matching this error is thrown

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) 
&& type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2) in cv::matchTemplate
```

[After searching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642693/2985796) it looks like the issue is that the two `Mat`s I am trying to use do not have the same "type". What I am not sure of is what this refers to. I assume it is the `Mat`s `CvType`, if I print out the `CvType` of the image and template I get a `type()` of [`4 == CvType.CV_32SC1`](http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html) for my template I get a `type()` of `20 == CvType.CV_32SC3`.

But I feel like this is not the correct `type()` I am trying to compare, I have feeling it refers to the data type of how the data is stored in the `Mat`? But I have no good links to back this up just remembrances from many SO searches.

Here is my code for loading in my jpg images into a `Mat`

```
Mat pic_ = Imgcodecs.imread("MyPath\\image.jpg");
pic_.convertTo(pic_, CvType.CV_32SC1);
```

Here the second line turns my `type()` from 20 to 16, though as per my last comment I don't think this is the proper way to alter the `Mat` to match the image?... Because `convertTo`'ing this `Mat` to match the type of the screen shot `(below) does not fix the error?

Here is how I am creating the image `Mat`

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage screenShot = rob.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
Mat screenImage = bufferedImageToMat(screenShot);
```

So I first take a screenshot with `Java.Robot.createScreenCapture` I then convert it to a `Mat` with

```
private Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage inBuffImg) 
{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(inBuffImg.getWidth(), inBuffImg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d= image.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(inBuffImg, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_32SC1);
    int[] data = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    mat.put(0, 0, data);

    return mat;
}
```

[From what I could tell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667034/2985796) the `BufferedImage` created by `Robot` is of type `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` which gives me an error "DataBufferInt cannot be cast to DataBufferByte" when trying to get the pixel data. So per the linked question I redraw the `BufferedImage` as type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` and pull out the data as a `DataBufferInt`.

**So in all,** should I be trying to match the `Mat.type()` or does my problem lie elsewhere? If not elsewhere how can I alter either of the `Mat`s so that they can be used with `Imgproc.matchTemplate` properly?

I feel like the easiest solution would be to convert the image loaded from file to match the screenshot `Mat`?

**EDIT:** The exact section of code that gives the error is below

```
// Mat imageTemplate is a function argument; the loaded jpg image
// Take a picture of the screen
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage screenShot = rob.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
Mat screenImage = bufferedImageToMat(screenShot);

// Create the result matrix
int result_cols = screenImage.cols() - imageTemplate.cols() + 1;
int result_rows = screenImage.rows() - imageTemplate.rows() + 1;
Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32SC1);

newStatus("ScreenType: " + screenImage.type());
newStatus("TemplaType: " + imageTemplate.type());

// Choose a matching method
int matchMethod = Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED;

// Do the Matching and Normalize
Imgproc.matchTemplate(screenImage, imageTemplate, result, matchMethod);
// Error occurs on previous line
```

Comment: You probably need to convert your template to grayscale. See how to use `cvtColor(... , COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: Should both the template and image be grayscale?

Comment: either both grayscale or both color.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a smart ass, but I'm pretty sure they're both color as it is?

Comment: If the template is `CvType.CV_32SC1` then it's a 1 channel image, i.e. grayscale :D

Comment: Hmm I guess this kind of gets the root of my question/problem. So in my function `bufferedImageToMat` if I use `CvType.CV_32FC3` and the same type when converting the read in template it "works". Though the data from the screen image is not written to the `Mat` in the function from the error "Mat data type is not compatible: 21" which I encountered when I first used the function (though it was 16). // I guess I am not sure what to ask from here except the novice question of "what went wrong"..?

Comment: And thank you for the understand :)! I guess I don't understand the type `CvType`, does this define both the data type of the data in the `Mat`rix and the depth of it?

Comment: Check [here](http://dovgalecs.com/blog/opencv-matrix-types/). Then the last CX stands for X number of Channels.

Comment: I can't investigate your problem further now, but the problem seems this one. Try to get both image and template with the same number of channels. Eventually use cvtColor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Miki pointed out in the comments the answer was getting the channe type to match for the image and template. I ended up changing my `bufferedImageToMat` function.

```
private Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage inBuffImg) 
{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(inBuffImg.getWidth(), inBuffImg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics2D g2d= image.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(inBuffImg, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    mat.put(0, 0, data);

    return mat;
}
```

My templates are read in as `CvType.CV_8UC3`, so it was just a matter of creating a `Mat` from the screen image with this type!

Comment: If that's the answer, don't forget to mark it as the answer. Glad you managed to figure it out!

Comment: I have to wait 2 days as a result of answering my own question, but I will at some point!